# RExcel code automation

Tags: vba, rexcel

Objective:

I am using Rexcel to run the ETS model. I want to automate the below mentioned code through VBA.

Issue:

The issue being faced is that vba does not execute the code after the second double quote i.e. in the ETS code mentioned below, the code is executed only till the end of the second double quote.

```
“etsz <- ets(zz,model="ZZZ")
etszP <- forecast(etsz,h=442)
```

i.e the code is executed till only `etsz <- ets(zz,model="`  and not `etsz <- ets(zz,model="ZZZ")`

How can the entire code be made to run in vba in order to automate the process ?

Answer (score 0):

or use single quotes

```
    “etsz <- ets(zz,model='ZZZ')"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: how does this not answer the question? If you run this code it will work. His will not work. Its clearer than the above answer (which you didn't comment on...?), since double quotes around quotes looks sloppy.

Comment: Sorry, I just flagged this answer as "needs attention" to get someone to review it and the comment was posted automatically without my involvement.